# What‘s the difference between OSI and OPC?

Tags: automation, communication, opc, osi, communication-protocol

OSI: Open Systems Interconnection Reference Model

OPC: OLE (Object Linking and Embedding) Process Control

I can‘t figure out the difference, since both of these refer to communication between machines.

Glad about any answer. Thanks

Comment: The difference is that they are not the same. Not even in the same ballpark. Your question is basically meaningless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Open Systems Interconnection (OSI) Model is a logical layout to define how systems should communicate with each other, using various protocols available at each of seven layers. It is a universal language to guide vendors and IT professionals to develop products and solutions or troubleshoot problems in networks. So, it is more like a conceptual tool than a specific protocol specification or a single technology.

On the other hand, OPC (Open Platform Communications, formerly OLE Process Control) can be described as an industrial standard M2M protocol for interoperability. The OPC standard is a series of specifications with a long history. The platform-dependent old specifications are called [OPC Classic](https://opcfoundation.org/about/opc-technologies/opc-classic/), and the next generation of OPC technology is known as [OPC UA](https://opcfoundation.org/about/opc-technologies/opc-ua/). In other words, it defines a specific communication solution in order to address a certain gap in industry.

Consequently, as a reference model and a generic tool, we can use the OSI model to develop a better understanding of how OPC deals with the problems we have in industrial networks today.